# how to detect same keyboard key press only once

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

I am designing a keyboard class that can detect the keyboard key press only one time but I still cannot figure out the way to do it. My goal is just check and perform the action only once when the same key is keep pressing or keep holding and no action performed when 2 action keys are pressed at the same time. For example, when I keep pressing or holding key A, action 1 is only perform once. Then I keep pressing or holding another key B, action 2 is also perform once. I cannot peform any action if I press key A and B at the same time.

There is two class inside KeyboardClass header and cpp file i.e. KeyboardClientClass and KeyboardServerClass.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: KeyboardClass.h
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#ifndef _KEYBOARDCLASS_H_
#define _KEYBOARDCLASS_H_

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Class prototype
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class KeyboardServerClass;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Class name: KeyboardClientClass
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class KeyboardClientClass
{
public:
    KeyboardClientClass( const KeyboardServerClass& KeyboardServer );
    ~KeyboardClientClass();
    bool KeyIsPressed( unsigned char keycode ) const;
    bool KeyIsPressedOnce( unsigned char keycode );

private:
    unsigned char tempKeyCode;
    const KeyboardServerClass& server;
};

class KeyboardServerClass
{
    friend KeyboardClientClass;

public:
    KeyboardServerClass();
    ~KeyboardServerClass();
    void OnKeyPressed( unsigned char keycode );
    void OnKeyReleased( unsigned char keycode );

   private:
        static const int nKeys = 256;
        bool keystates[ nKeys ];
        bool isKeyDown;
    };

    #endif


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Filename: KeyboardClass.cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include "KeyboardClass.h"

KeyboardClientClass::KeyboardClientClass( const KeyboardServerClass& KeyboardServer ) 
: server ( KeyboardServer )
{
    tempKeyCode = 257;
}


KeyboardClientClass::~KeyboardClientClass()
{}


bool KeyboardClientClass::KeyIsPressed( unsigned char keycode ) const
{
    return server.keystates[ keycode ];
}



bool KeyboardClientClass::KeyIsPressedOnce( unsigned char keycode )
{
    if ( tempKeyCode != keycode )
    {
        tempKeyCode = keycode;
        return server.keystates[ keycode ];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


KeyboardServerClass::KeyboardServerClass()
{
    for ( int x = 0; x < nKeys; x++ )
    {
        keystates[ x ] = false;
    }
}


KeyboardServerClass::~KeyboardServerClass()
{
    isKeyDown = true;
}


void KeyboardServerClass::OnKeyPressed( unsigned char keycode )
{
    keystates [ keycode ] = true;
    isKeyDown = false;
}


void KeyboardServerClass::OnKeyReleased( unsigned char keycode )
{
    keystates [ keycode ] = false;
    isKeyDown = true;
}
```

Firstly, I create the a KeyboardServer object to keep track of the keyboard messgae from Windows Procedure.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK SystemClass::MessageHandler( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch ( msg )
    {
        //************ KEYBOARD MESSAGES ************ //

        // Check if a key has been pressed on the keyboard
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        {
            if ( wParam == VK_ESCAPE )
                PostQuitMessage( 0 );

            // If a key is pressed send it to the KeyboardServer object so it can record the state
            m_KeyboardServer.OnKeyPressed( wParam );
            break;
        }

        // Check if a key has been released on the keyboard
        case WM_KEYUP:
        {
            // If a key is released then send it to the KeyboardServer object so it can unset the state for that key
            m_KeyboardServer.OnKeyReleased( wParam );
            break;
        }

        // ************ END KEYBOARD MESSAGES ************ //
}
```

Then, I create a KeyboardClient object at Game class to check whether a key has been pressed or not and perform the action based on key pressed.

```
if ( m_Keyboard.KeyIsPressed( KEY_B ) )
    // Do action A
else if ( m_Keyboard.KeyIsPressed( KEY_N ) )
    // Do action B
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit 30 of the `lParam` value for the [`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message indicates whether or not the key was previously down when the message was generated. You can use this to distinguish between the actual keypress and any subsequent key repeats.

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if (lParam & (1 << 30))
    {
        // this is a repeat
    }
    else
    {
        // first press
    }
    break;
```

But if, as it seems, you're trying to check in realtime which keys are down, you can do this using the [`GetAsyncKeyState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function rather than relying on tracking keystate via your message loop.

Comment: @user - [RTM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)