# How stop keys from spamming?

Tags: windows, input, onkeydown

I'm currently struggling with the windows "Inputs".
I would like to ask if there is a way to stop keys from spamming.

In fact I'm using this keyword:
case WM_KEYDOWN:
 // do some stuff

All the time I press the button it repeats firing functions
that depend on the pressing.
But I would like it to have waiting until it's released once
to be able to be firing once again.

Is there a keyword that checks that for me or do I have to hardcode that?
( searching on the net didn't help me out :/ )

Comment: (Check `WM_KEYUP` maybe?) Oops. Just set a flag to 0 and test it after you get this message. If it's not set, set it; if it's set, ignore the message. Reset it on `WM_KEYUP`.

Comment: Ok, I will try that... :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076158/how-to-detect-same-keyboard-key-press-only-once  look at that if (lParam & (1 << 30))
   { // repeat }
   else
   { // first click  }   :DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[how to detect same keyboard key press only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076158/how-to-detect-same-keyboard-key-press-only-once)  look at that if (lParam & (1 << 30))
            { // repeat }
            else
            { // first click  }   :DD